# Converting number within vector subsets to match string rows

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, sublist

Suppose I have a list of vectors (s) containing sublists of integers.

```
> s #List of 2 integers

> [[1]]
> [1]    23 900 1800 42 87

> [[2]]
> [1]    54 8777 13 1 2 3
```

The integers correspond to the row number within a dataframe containing characters, separated by " ".

```
> origninaldf

>[1,] "Apple"
>[2,] "Apples"
>[3,] "123_Street"
```

I would like to convert the list to a new dataframe (newdf) retaining the sublist number and row numbers (s) converted to characters based on dataframe (orignaldf).

```
> newdf
1   Zoo  ...
2   ... ... ... Apple Apples 123_Street
```

Thank you! (Still very new to coding within R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
lapply(s,  function(i) originaldf[ i[ i %in% 1:length(originaldf) ] ] )
```

Unclear what you mean by "retaining the sublist number", since operations are rarely destructive and the numbers do not appear in your desired result. Also you show an output with varying numbers of elements which would generally need to ba  list or a text file. Further confusion is caused by the output of 'originadf' which is being displayed as though it is not a dataframe but rather a matrix.

```
s <- list(c(23, 900, 1800, 42, 87), c(54, 8777, 13, 1, 2, 3))
origninaldf <- 

structure(list(nam = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("123_Street", 
"Apple", "Apples"), class = "factor")), .Names = "nam", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

> lapply(s,  function(i) origninaldf[ i[ i %in% 1:length(origninaldf)] ] )
[[1]]
data frame with 0 columns and 3 rows

[[2]]
         nam
1      Apple
2     Apples
3 123_Street
```

Comment: Your script works beautifully. However I wish to learn R, could you explain the use of lapply in very simple terms?

apply a function to generate a list, with increments based on the originaldf found in s?

Comment: Not exactly. `lapply` passes the individual elements of a list one  by one to a function. In this case it is passing the numeric vectors in `s` to that functions which is using them as indices into `originaldf`. The results of each function application are then retruned in a list, so for the first element not indices were matched and nothing was returned, while for the second set of vectors a three row dataframe was returned.